# Sum with left join and conditional where

Tags: mysql

I need assistance with a query for a report. I have an invoice table at the bottom of this scheme and need a way to get the total billed amount while conditionally filtering at higher points in this database scheme. I need to join into other tables that is causing the SUM function to return unwanted results.

Here is a diagram of the general scheme I'm working with.
[image]

Here is the database setup.

```
CREATE TABLE `hcm_compartments` (
`cid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`leaseid` int(10) NOT NULL,
`segment` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
KEY `leaseid` (`leaseid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `hcm_contracts` (
`cid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`leaseid` int(10) NOT NULL,
`groupid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`license` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`dateadded` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`BeginDate` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
KEY `leaseid` (`leaseid`),
KEY `groupid` (`groupid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `hcm_forest` (
`ForestID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ForestName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ForestLabel` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ForestID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `hcm_invoices` (
`iid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`contractid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`dateadded` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fiscalyear` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`totalbilled` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`totalpaid` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
PRIMARY KEY (`iid`),
KEY `contractid` (`contractid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `hcm_leases` (
`bid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`serial` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`forest` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`dateadded` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`acres` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
PRIMARY KEY (`bid`),
KEY `forest` (`forest`),
KEY `serial` (`serial`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


SET @timenow = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());

INSERT INTO hcm_forest (ForestID, ForestName, ForestLabel) VALUES (1, 'North', 'N'), (2, 'South', 'S'), (3, 'East', 'E'), (4, 'West', 'W') ;
INSERT INTO hcm_leases (bid, serial, forest, dateadded, acres)
VALUES
(1, 1000, 1, @timenow, 100),
(2, 1001, 2, @timenow, 125),
(3, 1002, 3, @timenow, 250) ;

INSERT INTO hcm_compartments (leaseid, segment)
VALUES
(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),
(2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3), (2, 4),
(3, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3) ;

INSERT INTO hcm_contracts (leaseid, groupid, license, dateadded, BeginDate)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'N-1000', @timenow, @timenow),
(2, 2, 'N-1000', @timenow, @timenow),
(3, 3, 'N-1000', @timenow, @timenow) ;

INSERT INTO hcm_invoices (contractid, dateadded, fiscalyear, totalbilled, totalpaid, balance)
VALUES
(1, @timenow, 2016, 125.00, 125.00, 0.00),
(1, @timenow, 2016, 150.00, 0.00, 150.00),
(1, @timenow, 2016, 100.00, 75.00, 25.00),

(2, @timenow, 2016, 1000.00, 125.00, 875.00),
(2, @timenow, 2016, 550.00, 550.00, 0.00),
(2, @timenow, 2016, 100.00, 0.00, 100.00),
(2, @timenow, 2016, 5000.00, 4500.00, 500.00),

(3, @timenow, 2016, 100.00, 100.00, 0.00),
(3, @timenow, 2016, 250.00, 50.00, 200.00) ;
```

Here is the query I am working with.

```
SET @fy = 2016 ;

SELECT SUM(i.totalbilled) totalbilled, l.forest
FROM hcm_leases l,
    hcm_compartments cm,
    hcm_contracts c,
    hcm_invoices i
WHERE i.contractid = c.cid
    AND c.leaseid = l.bid
    AND l.bid = cm.leaseid
    /*
    * The reason why I join into the hcm_compartments table is
    * because the user may wish to exclude all but a single
    * desired segment column from the hcm_compartments table.
    */
    #AND cm.segment = 1
    AND l.forest = 1
    AND i.fiscalyear = @fy ;
```

The total billed in forest 1 is 375. This query returns 1125, which is WRONG! If I group by i.iid, I get three returns for some reason -- seemingly due to the one to many relationship between leases and compartments. I've tried other ways of grouping and left joining, but nothing is getting me the accurate numbers.

Comment: I don't have time to test it at the moment, but I think the issue may be that you don't have any parameters telling MySQL how to actually `JOIN` the tables; that is, an `ON` clause indicating the relationship among foreign keys.  The `JOIN`s you have as-is can indeed lead to duplicate rows.

Comment: The first 3 items in the WHERE clause are instructions on how to join them. I use ON clauses for left joins. I've tried doing that here in other attempts, but I still get the wrong numbers.

Comment: Hang on.  Typing it up as an answer with more detail.

Comment: Hm.  I've been testing my solution, and I see a problem: `contractid` in `hcm_invoices` doesn't match any `cid`s in `hcm_contracts`, so no leases in `hcm_leases` can be matched up to any invoices in `hcm_invoices` with the data you've provided...

Comment: I didn't include the auto-incrementing columns, but they are there. Three contracts get inserted (1, 2, and 3). These three are referenced by these assumed record IDs in the invoices table. If you followed the scheme I posted above, you should get properly associating records.

Comment: Oh, I see, weird.  When I imported your data, my hcm_contracts table wound up with cids 4, 5, 6.

Comment: Oh, my fault. The stupid AUTO_INCREMENT settings came out in my tables. I'll adjust my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your joins are all backwards (and should be left joins anyway).  I like to start with the simplest possible query and build from there.

1. You need to filter based on forest, which is part of the `hcm_leases` table:

```sql
SELECT `l`.`forest` FROM `hcm_leases` `l` WHERE `l`.`forest` = 1;
```

2. Now you want to get the invoices for all the leases in forest 1.  Invoices are connected to leases by way of contracts:

```sql
SELECT `i`.`totalbilled`, `l`.`forest` FROM `hcm_leases` `l`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_contracts` `c` ON `l`.`bid` = `c`.`leaseid`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_invoices` `i` ON `i`.`contractid` = `c`.`cid`
WHERE `l`.`forest` = 1;
```

3. You want to be able to filter based on `segment`, which is in the `hcm_compartments` table:

```sql
SELECT `i`.`totalbilled`, `l`.`forest` FROM `hcm_leases` `l`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_contracts` `c` ON `l`.`bid` = `c`.`leaseid`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_invoices` `i` ON `i`.`contractid` = `c`.`cid`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_compartments` `cm` ON `cm`.`leaseid` = `l`.`bid`
WHERE `l`.`forest` = 1 AND `cm`.`segment` = 1;
```

4. But what you really want is the sum of the billed amounts (and filtering by fiscal year):

```sql
SELECT SUM(`i`.`totalbilled`) `totalbilled`, `l`.`forest` FROM `hcm_leases` `l`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_contracts` `c` ON `l`.`bid` = `c`.`leaseid`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_invoices` `i` ON `i`.`contractid` = `c`.`cid`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_compartments` `cm` ON `cm`.`leaseid` = `l`.`bid`
WHERE `l`.`forest` = 1 
    AND `cm`.`segment` = 1
    AND `i`.`fiscalyear` = @fy;
```

Result:

```sql
+-------------+--------+
| totalbilled | forest |
+-------------+--------+
|      375.00 |      1 |
+-------------+--------+
```

Now, if you **don't** want to filter by `segment`, you have to leave out the `JOIN` to `hcm_compartments` because MySQL doesn't know that two different rows created by the join, `bid`='1',`segment`='1' and `bid`='1',`segment`='2' are not unique.

```sql
SELECT SUM(`i`.`totalbilled`) `totalbilled`, `l`.`forest` FROM `hcm_leases` `l`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_contracts` `c` ON `l`.`bid` = `c`.`leaseid`
    LEFT JOIN `hcm_invoices` `i` ON `i`.`contractid` = `c`.`cid`
 WHERE `l`.`forest` = 1 
    AND `i`.`fiscalyear` = @fy;
```

The same answer could probably be achieved with a subquery while retaining the join to `hcm_compartments`, but since your result set doesn't include any fields from that table, it seems like the simplest approach to just omit it completely.

Comment: Yes, but note in my test query that the cm.segment part of the WHERE clause is conditional. The user input may not include it. In that case, I would need everything in forest 1 regardless of segment. That would be lease 1, contract 1, and invoices 1, 2, and 3. The result SHOULD be the same $375, but it's not. I get $1,125 ($375 x 3 compartments).

Comment: It's still because your joins are wrong.  You can omit the `cm`.`segment` portion of the `WHERE` clause and the result is the same.

Comment: I'm using your query. Just comment out the cm.segment line in the WHERE clause (simulating an instance where the user didn't want to filter by segment). You'll get 1125, which is wrong. I need the same 375 if I query everything in forest 1.

Comment: ...well I'll be darned.  Hm.

Comment: This behavior has been the crux of my headache. I've tried every combination of joins and grouping. If I can get it to hand me the correct return, whether a segment is selected or not, I've got it nailed.

Comment: See the updated answer.  Because `hcm_compartments` has a given lease in more than one compartment, I don't think you can `JOIN` that table unless you want to filter by compartment (otherwise the rows are duplicated, as we've seen)

Comment: @Lotharyx:  or we could use an EXISTS predicate in place of a join, to check for a matching compartment e.g. **`AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM hcm_compartments cm WHERE cm.lease_id =  l.bid AND cm.segment = 1)`**.  We can optionally include or omit the condition on segment, without introducing duplicates. Another alternative is to do a join to an inline view that returns distinct (unique) values of lease_id. e.g. **`JOIN ( SELECT c.lease_id FROM hcm_compartments c WHERE c.segment = 1 GROUP BY c.lease_id) cm ON cm.lease_id = l.bid`**.  Again, we could include or omit the condition on segment.

Comment: @spencer7593 I was distracted with other work today, but I did some initial testing with your EXISTS predicate. This looks like the solution I needed as it will not force me to change my query structure if the user input leaves out the segment, which has been my biggest desire. Please, post that as an answer. If the rest of my testing goes well, I'll select it as my solution.